# Qual o caminho mais curto para implementar 2FA com Angular e Spring

Tags: angular, spring-boot, login, spring-security, auth

estou usando as duas tecnologias mencionadas acima e gostaria de saber se vocês conhecem alguma biblioteca, framework ou exemplo funcional que facilite a implementação de uma autenticação em dois fatores com esse conceito de TOTP (Senhas dinâmicas e temporárias se entendi corretamente)
Atualmente uso uma autenticação simples com Spring Security baseado em usuário e senha mesmo provenientes do banco e disponibilizo também a autenticação via google por meio de uma biblioteca nativa do Angular que permite que eu salve tais usuários em minha base, entretanto infelizmente essa biblioteca (angularx-social-login) parece não oferecer nada pronto quando se trata em autenticação com dois fatores, seja via SMS, token, e-mail ou qualquer outra abordagem
Gostaria de saber se consigo ter uma POC de 2FA após meu fluxo de log in normal com alguma biblioteca ou facilitador dentro dessas duas tecnologias que mencionei ou se terei que seguir artigos para assimilar todos os conceitos e implementar manualmente toda a infraestrutura necessária para ter esse tipo de funcionalidade
Imagino que haja algo pronto ao menos para essa parte de leitura de QR code e emissão de token com um Google Authenticator, entretanto tudo que encontrei em pesquisas me pareceu um pouco verboso além do necessário e desatualizado ou mesmo usava tecnologias diferentes, vocês conhecem algo no escopo do Angular ou do Spring que possa me auxiliar nesse quesito?

Comment: Não existe nada pronto apenas para plugar e utilizar, existem libs para validar os TOTPs gerados pelos authenticators, mas você deve codificar as validações e fluxos.

Comment: Pode me passar o nome de alguma dessas bibliotecas?